# Django says it has to be a model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm using Django 1.3 and South those should be useful information. My problem is that, when saving the form it says:

```
ValueError at /reportforms/c13
Cannot assign "u'3'": "c13.job" must be a "joblist" instance.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:9000/reportforms/c13
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: Cannot assign "u'3'": "c13.job" must be a "joblist" instance.
Exception Location: /media/Django/path_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __set__, line 331
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Any idea what's wrong with this?

**models.py**

```
class joblist(models.Model):
    job_english                     = models.CharField(_('Job name in english'), max_length=255, default="")
    job_hungarian                   = models.CharField(_('Job name in hungarian'), max_length=255, default="")

class c13(models.Model):
    job                             = models.ForeignKey(joblist, verbose_name=_('Job'))
```

**forms.py**

```
class C13Form(ModelForm):
    job =   forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(item.pk, item.job_english) for item in joblist.objects.all()])
    class Meta:
        model = c13
        exclude = ('added_by')
```

**views.py**

```
    form = C13Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_c13 = c13.objects.create(
            job                             = joblist.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['job']),
            year                            = form.cleaned_data['year'],
            needlestick_injuries            = form.cleaned_data['needlestick_injuries'],
            staff_beginning                 = form.cleaned_data['staff_beginning'],
            staff_end                       = form.cleaned_data['staff_end'],
            working_hours_beginning         = form.cleaned_data['working_hours_beginning'],
            working_hours_end               = form.cleaned_data['working_hours_end'],
            added_by                        = request.user,
        )
        new_c13.save()
        return render_to_response('filled_out.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = C13Form(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'c13.html', { 'form': form })
```

Comment: what is the value of `form.cleaned_data['job']`

Comment: writing a `print form.cleaned_data['job']` after `if form.is_valid()` does not write anything to the terminal. But the django error page shows: job 
u'1' or u'2' etc depending on the selection I've made.

Comment: that means your form is not valid.. after if form.is_valid(): put and else and do print form.errors  it should tell you what the error is

Comment: Added more code, it still does not print anything if I writing a print after the `else:`

Comment: I suspect that the code you have shown isn't actually the code that is running -- does the error page clearly state that the exception is happening in that method of views.py? There's no way I can see that the code you've shown could try to assign a string to the `job` field.

Comment: `Exception Location: /media/Django/path_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __set__, line 331` this is the exception location, added more of the message above too.

Comment: Maybe you have to use ModelChoiceField instead of ChoiceField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Comment: Look upwards in the traceback to see what the last line that was actually in *your* code is -- are you calling form.save() somehow?

Comment: @abidibo it works with that fine thanks. If you write this as an answer I'll upvote it and accept it.
IanClelland: No, I'm not calling form.save(). Probably it was that I've not used the modelchoicefield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to use ModelChoiceField, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

```
job = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=joblist.objects.all())
```